# How do I switch connections using Node JS and mssql

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a situation where I need to query multiple SQL Servers to get a bunch of data. So, I am iterating over the SQL Servers first and then iterating over the queries that have to run. In my caller function, I have the below code

```
config.servers.forEach((element) => {
    sqlServer = element.server;
    element.queries.forEach(function(configQuery) {
        jsonKey = configQuery.key;
        sqlQuery = configQuery.query
        sqlDatabase = configQuery.database;
        var out;
        if (configQuery.parameter) {
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " WHERE " + configQuery.parameter + " = '" + partNumber + "'";
        }
        sqlHelper.sqlFun(sqlQuery, sqlServer, sqlDatabase, jsonKey, callback)
    })
```

And the sqlFun referes to the below function

```
let connection ;
function poolIt (sqlQuery,sqlServer,databaseName) {

if(!connection)
{
 //sqlServer_temp = sqlServer
 //instead of checking if connection is defined
 //we have to check if connection is open
  var dbConfiguration = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  server: sqlServer,
  database: databaseName,
  options: {
      trustedConnection: true
  }
}
 connection = sql.connect(dbConfiguration);
  }
}

function runQuery(sqlQuery,sqlServer,databaseName,sqlKey, callback) {
  poolIt(sqlQuery,sqlServer,databaseName)
  connection.then(pool =>{
  return pool.request().query(sqlQuery)
  }).then(result=>{
  if(callback)
  return callback(null,result.recordset, sqlKey )
   }).catch(err=>{
  if(callback)
  {
    console.log(err)
    return callback(err,null, sqlKey)
   } 

 })

}
module.exports.sqlFun = runQuery;
```

The problem I am facing is, for all the SQL Server connections that I am trying to establish, all of the are connecting to the same SQL Server. I understand that it has due to the function poolIt as I am checking there if a connection exists or not and if it exists, I am just coming out of the loop. I'd like to understand how to close this connection once I am done with executing queries in my iteration with the first SQL Server? I tried sql.close() and connection.close() but they are not working. The program just hangs for a long time if I use them.